# Issues with displaying 2 tables in SSRS in a single page

Tags: reporting-services, display

I have 2 tables: Table 1- Header with 10k records

Header table:

UID  || Po_number || Invoice Num|| Total Amount

101  || 41235     ||  abcdef    ||  5000

102  || 45324     ||  xyzghi    ||  7500

Likewise i have 10k records in header table above

Line table:

UID  || Po_number || Product    || unit_qty  || unit_price

101  || 41235     ||  pencil    ||  1        || 2500

101  || 41235     ||  pen       ||   2       || 1250

102  || 45324     ||  laptop    ||  1        || 7500

I have 50k records in line table.

Requirement is to have 25 records of header and the corresponding line details for that header information in each page.

The page should have 2 tables seperated. First table should show header information. Second table should be beneath the first table and should have line details information of the header 25 records.

How do i acheive this in SSRS using Report Builder?

Previous question:
I have 2 tables: Table 1- Header with 10k records and Table 2 line details corresponding to the header table and the number of records are 50k. The requirement is to display header on top of the page and line table beneath the header table. The details being displayed in the line table should correspond to the header table. The line and header table have a common field which is called uid(unique identifier). I need to create this report in SSRS Report Builder.

Work so far which i did:

1.) Created 2 datasets: Header and Line. Inserted a table for header and selected all the fields i will need to display. Likewise created another table for line and selected all the fields i need to display. The fields in line i used LOOKUP function pointing to the uid in header table and populated the data.
2.) I placed the line table just beneath the header.
3.) Since the number of records in header table are 10k, i restricted the rowcount to 50 so i can fit the header and line table in 1 page.

Issues i am facing:

1.) When i place the line table beneath the header table, i can't see the line table details, but when i place the line table next to header then i can see the detail of line table. I need the header table on top with 25 records and corresponding line details for that 25 header table records beneath the header table.

2.) The line table values are not being displayed in correspondence to the header table records being displayed in the page. which means if header table is displaying 25 records, the line table is displaying all the records. I need only the line details of the 25 header table records in that page.

Any help to solve this issue is greatly appreciated. Do let me know if you need any additional information. I am fairly new to IT and SSRS.

Comment: Can you edit your question and supply a small amount of sample data from each table as text and a mockup of your expected report output. As it stands it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do (at least not to me)

Comment: Hi i have edited the question as needed. Let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to create a subreport for each group of 25 headers and the associated lines. Then create a master report to repeat for each group.

It's a bit long winded but should give you what you want.

First create a report that handles just a single "*page*" of results.

So, create a new report and add a dataset (call it something like `dsHeaders` with the following dataset query

```
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    [UID], [Po_number], [Invoice Num], [Total Amount]
    , [PageN] = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [UID]) - 1) /25
   FROM myHeaderTable
  ) h
  WHERE h.PageN = @p
```

This step should automatically create a report parameter for you called `p`

Now add a second dataset called `dsLines` with the following query...

```
SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT d.*, p.PageN FROM myLinesTable d 
                JOIN ( SELECT 
                            [UID], [Po_number], [Invoice Num], [Total Amount]
                            , [PageN] = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [UID]) - 1) /25
                        FROM myHeaderTable
                        ) p 
                    on d.UID = p.UID
            ) a 
  WHERE a.PageN = @p
```

This will give us all the lines along with the same `PageN` values as the headers. If required, you can adjust the number of lines in each page/group by adjusting the `25` in each query.

Now add two tables to the report and drag and drop the fields from `dsHeaders` into the first and the fields from `dsLines` into the second.

Run the report and test it by putting in different values for the `p` parameter.

Once you are happy with it, save the report.

Next.

Create a new report and add a dataset (called say 'dsMain') with the following dataset query.

SELECT
[UID], [PageN] = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [UID]) - 1) /25
FROM myHeaderTable

Now add a table and remove two of the three generated columns. In the remaining column, right click the textbox and do "Insert ==> Subreport".

Now right-click the new subreport placeholder and choose "Subreport properties"

In the first tab, click the drop-down and choose the subreport you created earlier.

Now click the parameters tab, Click Add and choose "p" (it should be in the drop-down list) as the parameter and choose the `PageN` field as the value (again this should be in the dropdown list.

if for some reason the drop downs are not working, simply type `p` into the name column and `[PageN]` into the value column.

Finally, go to the rowgroup panel under the main designer and right click the rowgroup shown there (there should only be 1 rowgroup).

Open the properties and select "Between each instance..." in the page break settings.

Now run the main report and you shoudl see the subreport generated for each group of 25 records.

That should give you the basic report.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Worked like a charm. The only issue i am facing right now is, the data retrieval time(8 mins) for the main report is high.  Any suggestions on that?

Comment: If the tables are large it might be worth creating a view that has this additional column added then dumping the results of that to a physical table on a regular schedule and using that for reporting. As it stands it has to query the same table three times so if the table is very big that might table some time. Run the queries on their own in SSMS and see how long each takes then take it from there. Post a new question if you need help optimising.