SSRS - Pagination of two tables in a single page
Question :
we are facing an issue to achieve the pagination of data from two tables when these both tables are placed under single page. The requirement is to get the 12 rows from each table and show in the respective table of a page in SSRS report.
Current achieved Result :  Pagination of second table is not showing under the same page where the first table pagination rendered. Second page pagination is getting started only after the pagination for data of first table is completed. Overall the the pagination is happening sequential. But we need the pagination to happen parallel for both tables under the same page.
Please note that we applied grouping on each tablix by deriving the page number based on row number.
Any help is much appreciated in advance.

Expected Result : Pagination of first and second tables should be rendered in the same page across all the pages rendered as part of the pagination.


It appears that you posted the same image twice.

Thank you @RossBush for highlighting the image issue

Take a look at this answer to a similar question. If it does not, comment here and I will try to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75228793

thanks @AlanSchofield for your reply. we have tried by putting both the tables in a List component and applied the grouping on both the tables as well as List. Now its giving the desired output. Only limitation is the dataset for both the tables and List must be same, then only the pagination is working as per the requirement mentioned in my above question.
